# AWS/Kubernetes - Stickiness options not available for TCP protocols

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Why is default load balancer port 80 and 443 is considered as TCP ports? I want to test stickiness as shown in the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) either through yaml file or through aws console.

I was using nginx ingress and moved to default load balancer to test stickiness but I see the error `Stickiness options not available for TCP protocols`

[image]

I even tried specifying protocol `https` but it doesn't accept. It only allows  `"SCTP", "TCP", "UDP"`.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: httpd
      labels:
        app: httpd-service
      namespace: test-web-dev
   spec:
     #type: LoadBalancer
      selector:
        app: httpd
      ports:
        - name: port-80
          port: 80
          targetPort: 80
        - name: port-443
          port: 443
          targetPort: 443
        - name: port-1234
          port: 1234
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 1234
```

When I try ingress, I disable the service type `Loadbalancer` above

`nginx-ingress-lb-service.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  1234: "test-web-dev/httpd:1234"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
    - name: port-1234
      port: 1234
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1234

---
```

Answer (score 3):

Stickiness requires listener which operates in **layer 7** of [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), which in case of CLB, is provided by `http` and `https` listeners.

Since you are using `TCP` listener which operates in **layer 3**, stickiness is not supported. Thus, if you want to use sticky sessions, you **must change to** `http` or `https` listeners.

`UDP` and `SCTP` are invalid listeners for CLB. It only supports `TCP`, `HTTP`, `HTTPS` and `SSL`.

Comment: how do I change to https listeners?

Comment: @John For HTTPS you need SSL certiifcates. Can you try with HTTP first? Not sure how to use config file that you provided, but I would try just by replacing TCP with HTTP. Otherwise you have to check documentation.

Comment: I already use https. I tried protocol as HTTP and I got the error `only allows "SCTP", "TCP", "UDP"`

Comment: do you know any links that shows the example?

Comment: update the question with the ingress lb code

Comment: maybe ingress isn't the right thing here i guess

Comment: @John So if you can't change to HTTP, then have to stay with TCP and not rely on stickiness.

Comment: I posted my configs here with details about the apps and the issue. Can you see if you can answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238830/kubernetes-apache-to-tomcat-session-stickiness